# do while keeps repeating even when entered the correct value C

Tags: c, do-while, negation, logical-or, logical-and

I want to start a program of Y and N Q&A.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char answer[256];
    do {
    print("\nDo you want to delete yourself of the record?\n");
    scanf("%s", answer);
    printf("%s", answer);
    }while(answer != "Y" || answer != "N")
;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I declared a variable of type char of 256 elements, and then using scanf I recorded the user input and store it in answer. Then the loop will be keeping asking as long the user enters either an uppercase Y or N. The problem is that with this implementation the program keeps asking even if I enter a Y or N. Should I change the char declaration to a single character? I already tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char answer;
    do {
    print("\nDo you want to delete yourself of the record?\n");
    scanf("%c", answer);
    printf("%c", answer);
    }while(answer != 'Y' || answer != 'N')
;
    return 0;
}
```

but I received a warning:

```
warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type int' [-Wformat=]
scanf("%c", answer);
```

Does anyone has a clarification for this problem?

Comment: `answer != "Y"` is always true.  The address of `answer` is not equal to the address of `"Y"`.

Comment: You can't compare strings with `==` or `!=`. Either work witch characters or use string comparison functions.

Comment: @EugeneSh., they're not strings... they're chars

Comment: @JoelFan In the first snippet they are strings

Comment: For the second one - `scanf` should take `&answer`

Comment: `answer != 'Y' || answer != 'N'` in the 2nd code is also always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement

> Then the loop will be keeping asking as long the user enters either an
>   uppercase Y or N.

means that the loop will stop its iterations when the user will enter either "Y" or "N" will not it?

This condition can be written like

```
strcmp( answer, "Y" ) == 0 || strcmp( answer, "N" ) == 0
```

So negation of this condition (when the loop will continue its iterations) looks like

```
!( strcmp( answer, "Y" ) == 0 || strcmp( answer, "N" ) == 0 )
```

that is equivalent to

```
strcmp( answer, "Y" ) != 0 && strcmp( answer, "N" ) != 0
```

Pay attention to that you have to compare strings (using the C string function `strcmp`) not pointers to their first characters that always will be unequal.

So the condition in the do-while loop in the first program should be

```
    do {
    print("\nDo you want to delete yourself of the record?\n");
    scanf("%s", answer);
    printf("%s", answer);
    }while( strcmp( answer, "Y" ) != 0 && strcmp( answer, "N" ) != 0 )
;
```

That is there should be used the logical AND operator.

In the second program you have to use a call of scanf like this

```
scanf( " %c", &answer);
       ^^^^   ^
```

and the same logical AND operator

```
    do {
    print("\nDo you want to delete yourself of the record?\n");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    printf("%c", answer);
    }while(answer != 'Y' && answer != 'N')
;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. There is something I still cannot grasp though. In the condition after the while I put the logical OR operator because if answer is either "Y" or "N", then the program will stop. I cannot see why I have the use the logical AND, since I won't fulfill both condition when prompt to an answer.

Comment: @almrog "or" makes sense for the reasons to stop the loop.  But the `... while()` is looking for reasons to continue the loop.  So the answer cannot be Y AND the answer cannot be N.